# How do you upload an image in Sourceforge.wiki?

Tags: upload, sourceforge

There is an image icon in the edit bar

[image]

but, it just injects markdown into your code that needs the image URL. Nothing is uploaded. What should I do?

PS I have spotted that their [Documentation/Create New Page](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Create%20a%20New%20Project/) contains an image with url https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Create%20a%20New%20Project/attachment/uberproject-metadata.png. Please note the `<page name>/attachment/image` subfolder. So, there should be a way to attach image files to your pages. But how? I do not see any button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have discovered the ["Attach button" at the bottom of the page](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Wiki/#attachments). Sorry for the fuss. Sourceforge does host images at wiki.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, it only allows one screenshot at a time. It is kind of annoying. since, I had few more screenshots, so I had to edit the same post multiple times to add all the screenshots.